# Debian vimrc listchars

Tags: debian, vim

I would like to use the following characters in my debian .vimrc:

U+00BB  »
U+00B7  ·

However debian is not rendering the characters correctly. Does anyone know how to get these characters to appear properly?

Thanks,
Greg Sieranski

Comment: Is this in a terminal (ensure that it supports UTF8)?

Answer (score 1):

If this is in a terminal, ensure that it supports UTF8